# WebStorm does not recognise type after simple module.exports statment

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm

Im using in my **non** TypeScript server, some npm module which is written in TypeScript.

WebStorm does a good job auto-complete me:

[image]

I'm using a simple `module.exports` to make this `ldClient` accessible outside the file:

```
const LaunchDarkly = require('ldclient-node');
const ldClient                 = LaunchDarkly.init(process.env.LAUNCH_DARKLY_DEV_KEY);
module.exports                 = ldClient;
```

When requiring this file, WebStorm does not longer auto-completes me:

[image]

When using the `import * from '....'` WebStorm succeeds, however, for technical issues, I don't have the privileges to use it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Logged as [WEB-31531](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31531), please follow this ticket for updates